# MacBook Air forgotten password

Tags: macbook-pro

I last used my MacBook Air November 2016.  OS was up to date at that time.  I have forgotten my login PW (though I am pretty sure I know what it was). I am unable to reset login PW.  It is not part of my Apple ID linked hardware.  My disc is encrypted. I believe that is why no disc options are given to reboot and then change PW.

Comment: Have you tried Internet Recovery mode? https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201314

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to go... The way where you get your data back, and the way where you lose everything. Assuming you were using FireVault for your disk encryption,

## Reset using your Recovery Key (FileVault must be on)

If FileVault is turned on and you have a FileVault Recovery Key, you can use that key to reset your password.

At the login screen, keep entering a password until you see a message saying that you can reset your password using your Recovery Key. If you don't see the message after three attempts, FileVault isn't on.

Click the arrow button next to the message. The password field changes to a Recovery Key field.

Enter your Recovery Key, then follow the onscreen instructions to create a new password. Click Reset Password when done.

[Create a new login keychain](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT202860)

Or

## Wipe Everything

Boot into Mac Recovery Mode ⌘ + ⇧ + R.

Open the Terminal from the Utilities menu

Type `resetpassword`

A window should pop up to assist you...